# Purpose and usage of Open Record Type in M (Power Query Formula Language)

Tags: excel, record, powerquery, m

I've read through the language specification of Power Query's M" language, and came across the open record type. My understanding is that the open type allows for other fields, but I don't have a concrete understanding of what that means.

The way to declare a normal (closed) record is simply

```
myRecord = [name = "MyName", Age = 30]
```

From the language specification (5.4: Record Types):

```
myRecordType1 = type [Name = text, Age = number]       // Closed Record _type_
myRecordType2 = type [Name = text, Age = number, ...]  // Open Record _type_
```

however,

```
myRecord = [Name = "MyName", Age = 30, ...] // Not valid code
```

So it seems this concept is only about custom record *types*, rather than records in general, but I have no idea what to do with it. I tried this:

```
testFunc = (inputArg as myRecordType2) => 1 // Not valid code
```

... expecting it might make the function only accept a record with Name & Age Fields, and optional other fields, but no. Thought it might not work with the `as` keyword, but even this doesn't work:

```
testTable = Table.AddColumn(Table.FromRecords({[A=1]}), "newcol", each [Name="MyName", Age=30], type myRecordType1) // Not valid code
```

Could someone illustrate a use(case) for this?
Did I miss something in the language spec?

Comment: The answers below certainly help understand what it is a little better, but I'm still at a loss as to where this would be _useful_. Any ideas / use cases?

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation is as follows. Any comment is appreciated (even other thoughts).

Types are classifications of values. There are 2 flavors: primitive types (number, text etc.) and custom types, e.g. a specific table type or a record type.

For instance a table type is the set of column names, - types and any key values.
A table type can be specified first and then used when creating a table:

> ```
> Tabeltype = type table[Key = number, Value = text],
> TabletypeWithKey =  Type.AddTableKey(Tabeltype,{"Key"},true), 
> TableWithKey = #table(TabletypeWithKey, {{1, "A"},{2, "B"}, {3, "C"}})
> ```

Likewise, you can create record types.

However, you can’t directly use a record type when creating a record.
You can use Value.ReplaceType to “ascribe” a type to a value, e.g. a record type to a record, provided the record type is closed and has no optional fields.
Example in the code below.

I would expect a possibility to verify if a value matches a specific type, but that can only be done with primitive types (using keyword “is” or “as” or “Type.Is”).

So I created the code below to check for conformity of records to record types, according to my interpretation: I can’t give any guarantees it’s full proof.
Currently it’s a query so you can see what’s happening, but you can easily turn it into a function and use examples in the bottom half of the code that’s currently commented out.

> ```
> // Mext 2 lines to be decommented to turn the code into a function
> //let
> //    fnCheckConformity = (Record1 as record, RecordType as type) as logical =>
> let
>     // Next 2 lines to be removed when turning this code into a function
>     Record1 = [x = 1, A = 3, B = 4],
>     RecordType = type [x = number, optional y = text,...],
>     RecordTypeFields = Type.RecordFields(RecordType),
>     ToTable = Record.ToTable(RecordTypeFields),
>     RecordTypeTable = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(ToTable, "Value", {"Optional", "Type"}, {"Optional", "Type"}),
>     RecordTable = Table.FromColumns({Record.FieldNames(Record1),Record.FieldValues(Record1)},{"Record FieldName", "Record FieldValue"}),
>     JoinedTable = Table.Join(RecordTypeTable, "Name", RecordTable, "Record FieldName", JoinKind.FullOuter),
>     ConformityCheck = Table.AddColumn(JoinedTable, "Conform", 
>                         each if [Optional] = null then Type.IsOpenRecord(RecordType) else
>                              if [Optional] then true else
>                              if [Record FieldValue] <> null then Value.Is([Record FieldValue], [Type]) else
>                              false),
>     Result = List.AllTrue(ConformityCheck[Conform])
> in
>     Result
> // Add a comma after Result when turning the code above into a function
> /* The code below can be used when turning the code above into a function.
> // Examples:
>     OpenRecordType = type [x = number, optional y = text,...],
>     ClosedRecordType = type [x = number, y = text],
>     RecordA = [x = 1],
>     RecordB = [x = 1, A = 3, B = 4],
>     RecordC = [x = 1, y = "MarcelBeug"],
> //  RecordC is ascribed type ClosedRecordType:
>     RecordCTyped = Value.ReplaceType(RecordC, ClosedRecordType),
>     Conformity1 = fnCheckConformity(RecordA, OpenRecordType),   // true
>     Conformity2 = fnCheckConformity(RecordA, ClosedRecordType), // false
>     Conformity3 = fnCheckConformity(RecordB, OpenRecordType),   // true
>     Conformity4 = fnCheckConformity(RecordB, ClosedRecordType), // false
>     Conformity5 = fnCheckConformity(RecordC, OpenRecordType)    // true
> in
>     Conformity5 */
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Marcel's answer is great, but I could add a little more context.

It's true, there aren't a lot of uses for open record types in "M" today.

One place where it *could* have been useful is if we had the concept of "ragged" tables, e.g. this CSV with two, three, and four fields of data in the different rows.

```
A,B,C
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
```

Loading this CSV into PQ editor / Excel / PowerBI Desktop / powerbi.com will probably work, but it's not a good fit for a table value. In the "M" design today, a table is basically a list of closed records with non-optional fields (so you can't have a table row with more or less fields than the table columns).

Some other data sources like Azure Table or OData also could have used ragged tables. Right now, we'll return a table with some fixed columns, and a record column `[Content]` or `[Open Types]`.